# what altitude is the astronaut’s weight less then 5lb? Inquality word Problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, inequality

As the altitude of a shuttle increases, an astronaut’s weight   decreases until a state of weightless is achieved. The weight of a 125-lb  astronaut at an altitude of x kilometer above see level is given by
w=(6400¦(6400+x))^2
At what altitude is the astronaut’s weight less then 5lb?

Answer (score 0):

I think the right formula is:
\begin{equation}
F_w=m{GM_T\over (R_T+x)^2}\hspace{1cm} \text{where $R_T$=6400 km, $M_T=5,97\times 10^{24}$kg, G =$6,67 × 10^{−11}$ N m$^2$ / kg}
\end{equation}